# Decide when to use a particular .NET feature

Tags: .net

Is there any book that shows actually when to use a particular .NET feature?

For example:

(1) Remoting. In which scenario to use and what are the advantages and disadvantages.

(2) When to use a List and when a Dictionary. Which one is fast. etc.

**Edited**

Above are just examples. While developing which thing to use when, any book that teaches this. There may be many options, but which feature or class fits in which situation, that is what I want to know.

Answer (score 3):

There are already lots of other questions for book recommendations. For your specific points:

1. Don't use .NET Remoting in new applications. Use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) instead. Read the documentation on MSDN to find out what its intended use is:

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for building service-oriented applications. Using WCF, you can send data as asynchronous messages from one service endpoint to another. [...] A few sample scenarios include:
>
> - A secure service to process business transactions.
> - A service that supplies current data to others, such as a traffic report or other monitoring service.
> - A chat service that allows two people to communicate or exchange data in real time.
> - A dashboard application that polls one or more services for data and presents it in a logical presentation.
> - Exposing a workflow implemented using Windows Workflow Foundation as a WCF service.
> - A Silverlight application to poll a service for the latest data feeds.

2. Both are fast, but for different purposes. If you need fast lookup by key use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). If you need fast lookup by index use a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: Actually the above two things I gave for example. n broader term, is there any documentation available?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Get a good book on .NET for starters. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books/477751#477751) for suggestions.